# What will happen if we connect capacitor and battery directly?

Tags: batteries, capacitor

Let us take ideal capacitor and battery (no internal resistance) and connect them directly without any resistance.

If we take the equation of an RC circuit we get an indeterminate form in power of e (0/0 form).

How do we account for charge flow and current? I thought of relating it with the number of electrons but am not able to reach a convincing conclusion.

The energy stored in the capacitor would be half of the work done by the battery (as per general relations of capacitor). Where does this energy go when there is no resistance?

I am talking of charging by battery, not its discharging when we connect another cap.

Comment: It's the same principle when connecting a charged cap to a discharged cap.

Answer (score 2):

> If we take the equation of an RC circuit we get an indeterminate form in power of e (0/0 form.)

No surprise there – take an ideal source of power and connect it to an ideal sink of power, and the power flow will be infinite.

> The energy stored in the capacitor would be half of the work done by the battery (as per general relations of capacitor.)

No, it would be the same as the work done by the battery. Energy cannot just disappear, and in your model there's no resistive losses to convert it to heat.